# Docker compose: How to set env variable to use in a script

Tags: javascript, docker, docker-compose, webdriver-io

I'm running a webdriverIO (https://github.com/hulilabs/webdriverio) test via docker:

```
docker-compose run --rm webdriverio wdio
```

Now I need to set a variable with this command (ENV?) which can be used in the test file.

```
describe('my awesome website', function () {
  it('should do some chai assertions', function () {
    browser.url(url) // <-- I need to set the variable (dev vs. prod)
    browser.getTitle().should.be.equal('Website title')
  })
})
```

How can I do that?

---

**Configuration**

My *wdio.conf.js*:

```
exports.config = {
  host: 'hub',
  port: 4444,
  specs: [
    './specs/**/*.js'
  ],
  capabilities: [
    { browserName: 'chrome' },
    { browserName: 'firefox' }
  ]
}
```

My *docker-compose.yml* looks like this:

```
version: '2'
services:
    webdriverio:
        image: huli/webdriverio:latest
        depends_on:
            - chrome
            - firefox
            - hub
        environment:
            - HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_ADDR=hub
            - HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_PORT=4444
        volumes:
            - /app:/app

    hub:
        image: selenium/hub
        ports:
            - 4444:4444

    firefox:
        image: selenium/node-firefox
        ports:
            - 5900
        environment:
            - HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_ADDR=hub
            - HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_PORT=4444
        depends_on:
            - hub

    chrome:
        image: selenium/node-chrome
        ports:
            - 5900
        environment:
            - HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_ADDR=hub
            - HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_PORT=4444
        depends_on:
            - hub
```

Comment: Do you use nodeJs?

Comment: Yes I do. But I think this is not relevant here....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to set ENV variable into `docker-compose.yml`

```
services:
    webdriverio:
        image: huli/webdriverio:latest
        depends_on:
            - chrome
            - firefox
            - hub
        environment:
            - HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_ADDR=hub
            - HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_PORT=4444
            - APP_PROFILE=dev # <- here new variable
        volumes:
            - /app:/app
```

Then you need to read this varuiable in your app

```
describe('my awesome website', function () {
  it('should do some chai assertions', function () {
    browser.url(process.env.APP_PROFILE)
    browser.getTitle().should.be.equal('Website title')
  })
})
```

Also, in your `Dockerfile` you can put ENV variable with default value:

```
ENV APP_PROFILE=prod
```